# SciPy: making a spectrogram for an audio with log frequency scale and restoring the original signal from it

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, fft

So, the exact specification of what I am trying to achieve is in the question title. I've been playing with the [ARSS](http://arss.sourceforge.net/code.shtml), which is a C++ program to transform audio files into spectrograms with a logarithmic frequency scale and which can restore the sound from the generated spectrogram. I am trying to do something similar in python. Calling the ARSS executable from python is out of the case - the data is originally represented as a numpy array, so I'd have to export a wav file first, then make the conversion, then read the image. Furthermore, images obviously store 1 byte per pixel (ARSS outputs grayscale images), while I need float precision.

I've been playing with scipy.signal.spectrogram, however, there doesn't seem to be any way to make the frequency scale nonlinear (nperseg dependent on the frequency being sampled). Or is there?

So, my 3 questions are:

1. Is there any way to make the frequency scale logarithmic with scipy.signal.spectrogram or using any other scipy method?
2. Is there any way to restore the original signal from it's spectrogram using scipy?
3. Maybe there are better libraries to perform such a task?

Comment: 1.) just use numpy.log to transform the output and plot that. 2.) isnt the inverse https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.ifft.html or https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.ifft.html

Comment: `librosa` seems to do what you want. Creating a spectrogram: https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html, and inverting it: https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.inverse.mel_to_audio.html. Also check this blog post which does what you want in Python: https://timsainb.github.io/spectrograms-mfccs-and-inversion-in-python.html and this gist that the code came from: https://gist.github.com/kastnerkyle/179d6e9a88202ab0a2fe. Finally, check out the original paper for the inverse spectogram method: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1164317

Comment: @alkasm Thank you very much! Librosa is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Great! FWIW, I started to write an answer but deleted it once I found librosa---asking for external resources (like a good library to do X) is generally considered off-topic for Stack Overflow.